# Bash script in Linux

Tags: shell, ubuntu, scripting

I want to login to a remote system in ubuntu using a script file which will be executed in my system . The script contains the following commands

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'systemPwd' | ssh myMachine@192.168.0.59
```

By executing this script I could not log in to the system. It doesn't gets the password from the echo command. But I don't know how to use alternatives.

But I tried this script

```
#!/bin/bash
sshpass -p 'systemPwd' ssh myMachine@192.168.0.58 <<-'ENDSSH'
    #commands to run on remote host
    echo 'systemPwd' | sudo -S  shutdown-h now
ENDSSH
```

In the above script the `sshpass` has been used. The problem is that `sshpass` has to be installed first. Anyone suggest an alternative method for this which would make me to connect to remote system without `sshpass`.

Comment: Alternatively you could set up certificate based authentication and avoid having a password stored in your script.

Comment: Actually the problem is I want to make this method to work in Colibri T20 OS (angstrom Platform OS). So in that OS ,I'm unable to install the  ssh-keygen and ssh pass package in that colibri OS.

Comment: You don't need either of those packages. You just need some way of generating a certificate pair that you can use in the client and server.

Comment: Yeah You are right. But in case of ubuntu it's working without any package by simply using the command ssh-keygen . But in angstrom os that ssh-keygen is not available. That's the problem in my scenario.

Comment: So run `ssh-keygen` on a different machine; all it does is to generate a pair of keys: one for the client and one for the server.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use `SSH Keys`.

For creating `SSH Keys` use this command on the client machine:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Then you can copy the public key into the new machine's `authorized_keys` file with the `ssh-copy-id` command:

```
ssh-copy-id myMachine@192.168.0.59
```

After that you can login to your remote machine without password.

for more info: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2